# How to install Netgear WNA1000M- N 150 driver on Debian?

Tags: debian, networking, drivers

I installed debian.  Now I am worried how will my wifi adapter will work on it.

I found a thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806839 but didn't able to `install linux-firmware` and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential` also didn't work.

It doesn't know about linux-firmware.

Here are errors while installing above things:

`root@debian:/home/love# sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-headers-generic' has no installation candidate`

`root@debian:/home/love# sudo apt-get install linux-firmwareReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-firmware`

While adding repository the following error showed up:

`root@debian:/home/love# deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
bash: deb: command not found`

Here are some results of some commands:

`root@debian:/home/love# uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@debian:/home/love# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 138a:0005 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS301 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 2a70:f00e

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04d9:a0ac Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0846:9041 NetGear, Inc. WNA1000M 802.11bgn [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to U&L . Please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/335814/edit) by adding the output of `uname -a` and `lsusb`

Comment: @GAD3R I edited it with results. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `sources.list`:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then remove the wheezy repo.

There is an example [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList):

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Save and exit

Update your system:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install the `firmware-realtek` package :

```
apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Reference : [Debian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x)

Answer (score 0):

- is your APT cache up-to-date (`sudo apt-get update`) ?
- are the packages up to date (`sudo apt-get upgrade`) ?

Please provide the errors, otherwise it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: yes, both were done before using installation commands... how to get respiratory of Linux-firmware manually?

Comment: try  the following package (virtual) : 'linux-headers'. More info here : https://packages.debian.org/stable/linux-headers

Comment: I have edited the errors please have a look!